# Wrapping NSArray manipulations with '@synchronized', still crash

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronized

I have following class where I have several methods that manipulate with `cachedRequests` array

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *cachedRequests;    
}
+(MyClass*) instance; //Singleton
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (void) sendFromCache:(CacheData*)data;
@end

@implementation MyClass

static MyClass *sharedSingleton = nil;

+(MyClass*) instance{
@synchronized(self) {
    if(sharedSingleton == nil)
        sharedSingleton = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
  }
  return sharedSingleton;
}

   - (void) initialize 
   { 
        cachedRequests = nil;
    }

   - (void) processCache
  {   
       cachedRequests = [self getCachedRequests];
  }    

  - (void) sendNext
 {       
  @synchronized (self)
  {

    if (cachedRequests != nil && [cachedRequests count] == 0){
        return;
    }
    CacheData *data = [cachedRequests objectAtIndex:0]; // <-- here I get Crash 


    if (data != nil) {
        [cachedRequests removeObject:requestData];
    }
  }
}


@end
```

Looks like when I call: `CacheData *data = [cachedRequests objectAtIndex:0];` some other thread resets `cachedRequests` and I get this crash.

So what I did is:

```
   - (void) initialize 
   { 
      @synchronized (self){
        cachedRequests = nil;
      }
    }
```

The question are:

- is it enough? Do I need to add  `@synchronized (self)` for `cachedRequests = [self getCachedRequests];`
- **is it good practice to use:** `@synchronized (cachedRequests)` instead?

---

Crash details:

```
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18595af68 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 240 (NSArray.m:410)
3   living                          0x100c56a1c -[RequestCache sendNext] + 168
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `cachedRequests` is a *global* variable and shared by all instances of `MyClass`, so different intances are synchronising on different `self` objects to access the *same* array - this could easily be the source of your crash.

You probably meant to declared an instance variable by declaring it within braces:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
    NSMutableArray *cachedRequests;
}
```

You should also, as you suspect, protect each access to the variable.

HTH

Comment: updated, thank you, ` NSMutableArray *cachedRequests;` I declare in header

Comment: So what question remains? Are you still getting crashes with `cachedRequests` being an instance variable and after protecting each use of it with `@synchronized`?

Comment: I protected with `@synchronized` only `sendNext` method as mentioned above. But still got crash. So now I wrapped `@synchronized`  at `cachedRequests = nil;` My class is Singleton.  Please see questions I asked. Thanks

Comment: As the answer says you must "protect each access to the variable" - *all* instance methods which access the instance variable must have exclusive access to it or else there is no exclusive access!

Comment: BTW It is better to declare the instance variable in the implementation, as shown in the answer, rather than in the header, as shown in your edited question. Instance variables declared in the header can easily be accessed from outside the implementation, which in this case would bypass your threading protection. Instance variables declared in the implementation cannot be directly accessed from outside.